# how to capture text from a web page with ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, automated-tests

I am running an automated test script written in Ruby in which I get a result page, I would like to capture some of the text on the page and print them in a file. Can anyone assist with this effort?

Comment: Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)...

Comment: I agree with @ArupRakshit - Nokogiri will make this simple.

Comment: What have you tried? We can't help when we don't know what you've done. As the above comments say, Nokogiri is a starting point, but by itself it won't help at all. Read the documention for OpenURI first.

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments say, use Nokogiri.

Install it with `gem install nokogiri`.

To print the first top-level heading from example.com:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com/"))
puts doc.css("h1").first
```

For more information on finding the text you want, try [this guide](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)